# Horrible permissions bug, anonymous users can edit products

Tags: users

I have a Drupal Commerce site. I'm using `Content Access` to only allow users with the role "Vendor" to "Edit own product." Nobody else is allowed to edit any products. This is the only module I'm using afaik that controls permissions.

And yet.... **everybody** is able to edit **all** products! Even guests! This bug is horrifying.

I've tried

- clearing all caches
- emptying the node_access DB table
- Rebuilding permissions from the status report
- completely disabling editing products for anyone
- disabling and uninstalling the Content Access module

Here is my access control for the Product content type (it was originally called Produce, hence the machine name being `produce`)

[image]

And yet when I go to view a product, even as an anonymous guest, it shows the "View" and "Edit" tabs. And when I click "Edit" I can actually change the content and save the node!

One node example is node id 78. If I look at the `node_access` table in the DB, it shows this:

```
nid   gid   realm   grant_view   grant_update   grant_delete
78    0     all     1            0              0
```

If rebuilding permissions doesn't work, disabling Content Access doesn't work, then.... I have no idea where to go from here.

**Update**

I've installed Devel and am checking which modules implement `hook_node_access`

```
$ drush fn-hook node_access
Enter the number of the hook implementation you wish to view.
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  commerce_marketplace
 [2]  :  node
 [3]  :  features
```

Comment: Do you use drush?  What does `drush php-eval 'module_implements("node_access");'` list?  `hook_node_access()` doesn't get recorded in the node_access table.

Comment: FWIW this doesn't appear to be a bug with Drupal Commerce - I've just checked three separate sites and none have this issue

Comment: @MPD sorry ran drush from the wrong folder. When I run that I get no output.

Comment: First of all, Commerce create producs as separate entities from nodes. If your products are nodes there's something weird there (AFAIK, but I haven't used last Commerce releases, or you are talking about  Product Displays). Secondly, this is not a Drupal nor Commerce bug, I can assure you. This must be a bad configuration issue. Some permissions bypass some security checks (like Content Access). You should check anonymous user permissions in the permissions page, specially the nodes and products related ones.

Comment: @tunic The only box checked for anonymous users is "View published content." I'm using Product Variations so yes, there is both a Content Type and a Product Variation Type. On the permissions page I have "Create" and "View own" checked for both, for Vendors only.

Comment: @MPD I installed Devel and used `drush fn-hook` and it's giving me 3 modules: commerce_marketplace, node, and features.

Comment: @tunic Snap.  Forgot that Commerce doesn't use nodes.

Comment: @MPD But Commerce does use nodes. There is a node for each product, as well as multiple variations. The variations contain the price, image, weight, etc. Those permissions are working fine - the anonymous user can't edit them. The anonymous user can only edit the node fields - title, description, tags. The URL is on `node/78/edit`. So yes, Commerce creates separate entities but it uses nodes too, and the node permission is the problematic part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Node access rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/7) can be a little hard to debug.  You need to enable the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module, and the Devel Node Access submodule.

Then goto your block configuration.  There will be two new blocks: Devel Node Access and Devel Node Access By User.  Add these to your page, and configure them for your admin role(s).  Also goto the Devel settings (admin/config/development/devel) and enable Devel Node Access debug mode.

Then visit a page with access problems.  Look at the debug info.

The Devel Node Access block will show you the `{node_access}` rows for the node in question.

The Devel Node Access By User block will show you who has permission to do what, and why.

Then you need to do some sleuthing.  If it is a permission, then you need to find that permission and edit it.  If it is a [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), then you need to find the module that is implementing it.  If it is a grant, then you need to use the realm/gid and track down who is implementing a [`hook_node_access_records()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7) with that pair.

The [`module_implements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) function can be used to track down who is implementing what.  I typically do this with

```
drush php-eval 'print_r(module_implements("node_access"))';
drush php-eval 'print_r(module_implements("node_access_records"))';
```

My *guess* is that one of your features has a rogue `hook_node_access()` in it.  You could also try disabling your features one by one and seeing what happens.

Comment: Thank you a million times. The Devel blocks are telling me exactly which module is the problem child. I haven't figured out why it's doing this, especially when it was working before - maybe a buggy upgrade - but this is a huge help.